# How to tokenize compound sentences based on the conjunctions?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, algorithm-request, pretrained-models, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to tokenize sentences of a document for aspect-based sentiment analysis. There are some sentences that consist of more than one topic. For example,

> The touch screen is good but the battery is weak

or

> Their smartphones are great and their TVs are perfect.

I want to tokenize sentences based on these "conjunctions". To be more specific, for example, in the first case, I want to get these tokens:

> [The touch screen is good, the battery is weak]

Existing tokenizers split documents based on punctuation. Even if I spit based on words such as `but`, `and`, and so on, it is possible to get splits that are words. For example

> the phone is handy and cool

will be

> [the phone is handy, cool].

but instead it should remain the same, that is

> [the phone is handy and cool].

Is there any pre-trained model for this task? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want to tokenize sentences based on these conjunctions". Can you provide an example of how you would like the given example sentences to be tokenized? Can you also explain why existing solutions don't meet your requirements? Please, edit your post to clarify all of this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added more explanation. I really appreciate it if you help me.